# Different ways of using sas dataset (sas7bdat) in R

Tags: r, csv, statistics, sas, rstudio

I have a SAS dataset that is at least about 100MB+. I am trying to read it into R. I found of the following.

```
sas7bdat package
read.sas7bdat
```

But I am looking into to see if this is the common way that is used? Or if there could be another way that is recommended?

Another approach I am trying is to convert sas7bdat to csv, but if I did it - are there any potential issues I should be aware of?  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have access to a licensed version of SAS?

Comment: Yes I do. I have it on the same machine I have R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access your SAS data with something other than SAS, it's generally good practice to use the XPORT engine to export it as a "transport file" (extension: `.xpt` or `.xport`). SAS intends this file format to be independent of operating environment (see [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/movefile/59598/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002576216.htm)), so it can be used by other software.

In contrast, `.sas7bdat` files are designed only to be used by SAS. Reading them into R necessarily depends on having a licensed version of SAS on your computer or (as in the case of the sas7bdat package you mentioned) [reverse engineering](http://biostatmatt.com/archives/1216) a solution. For people stuck with a `.sas7bdat` file and no SAS license, you can try downloading a free trial of [Stat/Transfer](http://www.stattransfer.com/).

Once you have the `.xpt` file, you can read it into R like this:

```
require(foreign)
read.xport("path/to/file/data.xpt")
```

There are other perfectly good solutions for reading in `.xpt` files, like `sas.get()` (Hmisc package) and `read.ssd` (foreign package), but they can be harder to implement. The SASxport package is a newer attempt to improve on the solution I just gave above, but I can't vouch for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

library(haven)

datain <- read_sas("filename.sas7bdat", NULL)

Or you can cheat and click and point in RStudio